# How do I create an IComparer for a Nunit CollectionAssert test?

Tags: c#, nunit

I wish to create the following test in NUnit for the following scenario: we wish to test the a new calculation method being created yields results similar to that of an old system. An acceptable difference (or rather a redefinition of equality) between all values has been defined as

```
 abs(old_val - new_val) < 0.0001
```

I know that I can loop through every value from the new list and compare to values from the old list and test the above condition.

How would achieve this using Nunit's `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` method (or some `CollectionAssert` method)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well there is method from the NUnit Framework that allows me to do tolerance checks on collections. Refer to the [Equal Constraint](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.5). One uses the `AsCollection` and `Within` extension methods. On that note though I am not 100% sure regarding the implications of this statement made

> *If you want to treat the arrays being compared as simple collections,
>   use the AsCollection modifier, which causes the comparison to be made
>   element by element, without regard for the rank or dimensions of the
>   array.*

```
 [Test]
 //[ExpectedException()]
 public void CheckLists_FailsAt0()
 {
    var expected = new[] { 0.0001, 0.4353245, 1.3455234, 345345.098098 };
    var result1 = new[] { -0.0004, 0.43520, 1.3454, 345345.0980 };
    Assert.That(result1, Is.EqualTo(expected).AsCollection.Within(0.0001), "fail at [0]"); // fail on [0]    
    }

[Test]
//[ExpectedException()]
public void CheckLists_FailAt1()
{
    var expected = new[] { 0.0001, 0.4353245, 1.3455234, 345345.098098 };
    var result1a = new[] {  0.0001000000 , 0.4348245000 , 1.3450234000 , 345345.0975980000  };                      
    Assert.That(result1a, Is.EqualTo(expected).AsCollection.Within(0.0001), "fail at [1]"); // fail on [3]        
    }

[Test]    
public void CheckLists_AllPass_ForNegativeDiff_of_1over10001()
{
    var expected = new[] { 0.0001, 0.4353245, 1.3455234, 345345.098098 };
    var result2 = new[] {  0.00009900 , 0.43532350 , 1.34552240 , 345345.09809700 };
    Assert.That(result2, Is.EqualTo(expected).AsCollection.Within(0.0001)); // pass      
 }

 [Test]
 public void CheckLists_StillPass_ForPositiveDiff_of_1over10001()
 {
    var expected = new[] { 0.0001, 0.4353245, 1.3455234, 345345.098098 };
    var result3 = new[] {  0.00010100 ,  0.43532550  , 1.34552440 , 345345.09809900 };
    Assert.That(result3, Is.EqualTo(expected).AsCollection.Within(0.0001)); // pass
 }
```

Comment: Well, I'll be damned - I've never seen that construct before.  Good find!

Answer (score 13):

The current answers are outdated. Since NUnit 2.5, there is an overload of `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` that takes a `System.Collections.IComparer`.

Here is a minimal implementation:

```
public class Comparer : System.Collections.IComparer
{
  private readonly double _epsilon;

  public Comparer(double epsilon)
  {
    _epsilon = epsilon;
  }

  public int Compare(object x, object y)
  {
    var a = (double)x;
    var b = (double)y;

    double delta = System.Math.Abs(a - b);
    if (delta < _epsilon)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    return a.CompareTo(b);
  }
}


[NUnit.Framework.Test]
public void MyTest()
{
  var a = ...
  var b = ...
  NUnit.Framework.CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a, b, new Comparer(0.0001));
}
```

Comment: This also works for MsTest! `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert.AreEqual(a, b, new Comparer(0.0001));`

Answer (score 0):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4.1) does not define any delegate object or interface to perform custom checks to lists, and determine that a expected result is valid.

But I think that the best and simplest option is writing a small static method that achieve your checks:

```
    private const float MIN_ACCEPT_VALUE = 0.0001f;

    public static void IsAcceptableDifference(IList collection, IList oldCollection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new Exception("Source collection is null");
        if (oldCollection == null)
            throw new Exception("Old collection is null");
        if (collection.Count != oldCollection.Count)
            throw new Exception("Different lenghts");

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            float newValue = (float)collection[i];
            float oldValue = (float)oldCollection[i];

            float difference = Math.Abs(oldValue - newValue);
            if (difference < MIN_ACCEPT_VALUE)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    string.Format(
                        "Found a difference of {0} at index {1}",
                        difference,
                        i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the approach. NUnit does cater for collection comparisons. Have a look at my answer

Comment: Since NUnit 2.5, there is an overload of `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` that takes a `System.Collections.IComparer`.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked how to achieve your desired test using a CollectionAssert method without looping through the list.  I'm sure this is obvious, but looping is exactly what such a method would do...

The short answer to your exact question is that you can't use CollectionAssert methods to do what you want.  However, if what you really want is an easy way to compare lists of floating point numbers and assert their equality, then read on.

The method `Assert.AreEqual( double expected, double actual, double tolerance )` releases you from the need to write the individual item assertions yourself.  Using LINQ, you could do something like this:

```
double delta = 0.0001;
IEnumerable<double> expectedValues;
IEnumerable<double> actualValues;

// code code code

foreach (var pair in expectedValues.Zip(actualValues, Tuple.Create))
{
    Assert.AreEqual(pair.Item1, pair.Item2, delta, "Collections differ.");
}
```

If you wanted to get fancier, you could pull this out into a method of its own, catch the AssertionException, massage it and rethrow it for a cleaner interface.

If you don't care about *which* items differ:

```
var areEqual = expectedValues
    .Zip(actualValues, Tuple.Create)
    .Select(tup => Math.Abs(tup.Item1 - tup.Item2) < delta)
    .All(b => b);

Assert.IsTrue(areEqual, "Collections differ.");
```

Comment: close, but still requires a loop - NUnit does cater for collection comparisons. Have a look at my answer

Comment: Good find.  My pedantry insists, however, that there is most definitely looping happening in your method as well - just so's you know.

Comment: This solution is incorrect, because it considers the arrays [1,2,3] and [1,2,3,4,5] to be equal. If the inputs to Zip are different lengths, the result will be the same length as the shortest input.

Comment: Since NUnit 2.5, there is an overload of `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` that takes a `System.Collections.IComparer`.